# how to add vscode enable proposed API arguments automatically?

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I want to add the 'enable proposed API' argument automatically. when calling the activate function in a VSCode extension. How can I achieve this?

1. Ctrl+Shift+P -> Preferences:Configure Runtime Arguments: [image: Ctrl+Shift+P -> Preferences:Configure Runtime Arguments]
2. when calling the activate function Add this argument.(argv.json): [image: when calling the activate function Add this argument.(argv.json)]

Installed Extension -> Extension Activated -> add enabled-proposed-api=["myExtension"] automatically
-> enabled-proposed-api applied.